Is there a way to use the "inspectUri" property in the IIS Express debug profile?
Context: I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app that uses Blazor WASM components. I would like to use IIS Express so my app can use Windows authentication.
The inspectUri property is required to debug Blazor components (see Microsoft's documentation here). It works fine in the https profile, but not in the "IIS Express" profile. Is there an alternative I can use for "IIS Express"?
I have this JSON in my launchSettings.json file:
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:17623",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      },
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7216;http://localhost:5159",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

Is there an alternative to inspectUri for the IISExpress commandName, or something else I can try to get debugging working for my Blazor components?

Since the inspectUri property doesn't directly apply to IIS Express profiles, you can set up a proxy configuration in your launchSettings.json. Add a Kestrel profile with the necessary inspectUri for debugging and configure IIS Express to forward requests to this Kestrel instance running on a different port.

"configure IIS Express to forward requests to this Kestrel instance running on a different port" - I'm not sure how to implement this. As I understand it you can only launch Kestrel or IIS Express.
